# Safely escaping input parameters when used with aggregate expressions?

Tags: python, django

I am working in Django 1.8. I am currently running the following unsafe query using `django.db.connection`:

```
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    param = 'cost' # Actually obtained as a GET parameter
    query = "SELECT date, pct_id, SUM(%s) as val " % param
    query += "FROM mytable "
    query += "GROUP BY pct_id, date ORDER BY date"
    cursor.execute(query)
```

This works, but is obviously vulnerable to SQL injection. Instead I want to escape `param` before passing it into the query string.

So I'm trying this:

```
    query = "SELECT date, pct_id, SUM(%s) as val " 
    query += "FROM mytable "
    query += "GROUP BY pct_id, date ORDER BY date"
    cursor.execute(query, param)
```

However, this gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

How can I safely escape this parameter?

Comment: `%s` in `query` string

Comment: AFAIK you cannot parametrize column or table names.

Comment: Aside: `param` should be a sequence, e.g. tuple or list.

Comment: And why are you completely bypassing the ORM when this query is a no-brainer? -> `MyModel.objects.order_by('date').values('date', 'pct_id').annotate(val=Sum(param))`

Comment: @LittleQ but that would be vulnerable to injection, wouldn't it?

Comment: `%s` in `query` is the only conversion, there maybe something wrong with cursor.execute(query, param)

Comment: @LittleQ not sure I understand what you're suggesting, sorry...

Comment: I didnt make myself clearly previously, may my suggestion help